# How to escape from an infinite loop in Flash CS5?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Right now. My Processor is trembling as hell because of my Flash looping infinitely and I haven't saved my file. How do I escape from it? Is there a default loop count in Flash CS5? I do hope so there is. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: Flash should automatically stop a script thats looping infinitely. Are you sure its actually infinite (and not making micro-changes to a property, or whatever)? And... you can always kill flash with the task manager...

Comment: Just be sure to kill the flash player and not the Flash CS5 ide

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have not saved your file, Flash CS5 has functionality that let's you recover lost files. It also auto-saves in case the program crashes.